# Building a project with unit tests in one executable

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, try-catch

I'm setting up project in C++ using CMake and Catch/gmock for unit testing (it's not very important, unit testing frameworks are working similarly) . I'm targeting Windows (MSVC compiler) and Linux platforms. I'd like to put all the tests in single executable as desribed in Catch's [tutorial](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#scaling-up) . For unit testing purposes I will probably make some fake implementations/mocks. I'm afraid when I will build everything into an one executable (files with test source, project sources, fake implementations) I will get linker multiple definition errors, since there will be multiple function definitions: true and fake ones. Possible solutions I see now:

1. Build multiple executables, every with right implementations - I see this worst solution, because I will end up with bunch of files, which I will have to execute to test program (probably via some script, but it's not convenient option).
2. Compile each test with it's dependencies to shared library which all will be linked with main test runner executable. I think it will be quite hard to achieve, especially I'm not familiar with Linux shared libraries. For Windows it should be doable with some dllexports, but not really easy.

   How should are solve this problem? What are real world solutions for this? Maybe I don't see something really simple and I'm looking for a nonexistent  problem? I'd like quite easy, multi platform solution.

Comment: Are you afraid or does this actually happen? Do you have some *unit* tests which don't need (some of) the real things and some more integration tests that need a mix? Could you have a couple of tests exes in that case?